# Does react-data-grid 7.0 fix draggable column resizing issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-data-grid

We have been waiting for the draggable column resizing issue to be fixed for close to 6 months

- https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/pull/1700
- https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/pull/1449
- https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/1400

Is this issue finally going to be fixed in the upgrade to version 7.x or is yet another pull request going to be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates in v7: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/1400
v7 is still in canary unfortunately.